# 3rd Normal form Confusion

Tags: database, erd

So I was normalizing this table. I came to realize that there is transitive dependency. Because institute Name and city depends on institute code. So I have to create new table and shift these column there. But the problem is, institute code repeats for different institutes. So is it necessary to create my own unique ID for this newly created tablet? or can I go with foreign key only????
[image: This Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transitive dependency is a dependency of the form A → B → C, where A is a key and B is a non-key attribute. The transitive dependency I think you are referring to here is Countt → instituteCode → instituteName.

However, you say that "institute code repeats for different institutes", which seems to suggest that there is *not* a dependency between instituteCode and instituteName. Dependency requires that there is exactly one possible value for the dependent (right-hand side) attribute for any given value of the determinant (left-hand side). Presumably if the same instituteCode can be used for different institutes then those different institutes might have different names? If that is so then the transitive dependency Countt → instituteCode → instituteName does not hold and there is no violation of 3NF by having these attributes in the same table. This is only my assumption; you need to find out for yourself what dependencies actually apply.

If Countt → instituteCode → instituteName *does* hold then you can create a new relation for instituteCode and instututeName where instituteCode is the primary key (because instituteCode → instituteName).

> is it necessary to create my own unique ID for this newly created
>   table

No. Normalization never requires new attributes to be created.

Comment: ok that helped. but for some institutes, there is only institute Name and city,  in that case, unique ID from my side is necessary right? @sqlvogel

Comment: What attribute(s) identify an institute? Name? Name and City? You can invent your own alternative key values but that won't help unless you can identify which institute each key value belongs to.

Comment: Correct, but if I make composite key ( of city and name), then it would take too much memory. but if I declare my own institute ID then it would take less memory and  comparison would be fast also when I connect these two tables with join.. Don't you think?

Comment: @zohaibkhan You need to learn a lot more about design basics before you have to worry about space or speed. And when you do it should be after you have demonstrated that there is a problem. And you should not confuse optimization with normalization.

Comment: Correct. Thnx for nice suggestion @philipxy